# Panel multinomial logit with varying choice set

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, panel-data, multinomial-logit

Say I have 100 individuals and 100 periods. In each period, they choose 1 out of the same 3 unordered options (a, b and c). An individual's choice at time t would depend on some others' choices at time t-1.

I also code their choice in the following way:

- Case 1. a is coded as 1, while b and c are code as 3.
- Case 2. b is code as 1, a is coded as 2, c is coded as 3.
- Case 3. c is coded as 1, while a and b coded as 2.

Which Case applies depends on the others' choices at time t-1.
Currently I am using panel multinomial logit for the coded options (i.e., 1, 2 and 3). My concern is that with Case 1 and 3, the number of alternatives is 2 instead of 3. And this varies across time and individuals.

That is I have varying choice set instead of a fixed set. It makes it inappropriate to use multinomial logit. My question is what model I could use to deal with varying choice set. Is mix logit suitable for this?